# AngularJS Typeahead callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, typeahead.js

I know there is something wrong related to this callback function. But I'm not sure what is the best way to fix this.

I have a resource:

```
.factory("AutoCompleteResource", function ($http) {
    return {
        getAutoComplete: function (searchTerm) {
            $http.get('/cdeCompletion/' + searchTerm, {}).then(function (response) {
                response.data;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

this is the controller:

```
 $scope.getAutoComplete = function (searchTerm) {
    AutoCompleteResource.getAutoComplete(searchTerm);
}
```

this is the html view:

```
<input name="searchTerms" id="searchTerms" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ftsearch"
                       ng-maxlength="500" placeholder="Search Common Data Elements"
                       typeahead-wait-ms="500" typeahead-min-length="3"
                       typeahead="searchQuery for searchQuery in getAutoComplete($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                       typeahead-focus-first="false" typeahead-on-select="gotoSearch()">
```

What is the best way to fix the error here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise to the typeahead as it can handle promise and auto resolve it for data, i.e

```
.factory("AutoCompleteResource", function ($http) {
    return {
        getAutoComplete: function (searchTerm) {
          //Return here
           return $http.get('/cdeCompletion/' + searchTerm, {}).then(function (response) {
                return response.data; //return here
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
$scope.getAutoComplete = function (searchTerm) {
    //Return here
    return AutoCompleteResource.getAutoComplete(searchTerm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you explain why this works?

Comment: @sh977218 You are welcome.. :) Instead you should ask why your code did not work. Because you are setting a function to be called when typed and you dont return anything from that function. Here we are returning a promise which typeahead knows how to resolve and get data from. Regardless of this case you should always try to return promise from your services which does an async operation which returns a promise (in this case $http).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call in bs-options

```
<input bs-typeahead id="txtJobNumber" type="text" class="form-control typeahead"
                   typeahead-wait-ms="10" typeahead-append-to-body="true"
                   ng-model="JobNumber" bs-on-select="OnJobSelected"
                   bs-options="item.JobNumber for item in getMatchedJobNumbers($viewValue)" 
                   data-limit="Infinity" data-min-length="3" data-html="1" data-auto-select="true" />
```

Add this to call your Api when user types in typeahead input box

```
$scope.getMatchedJobNumbers= function (value) {

        
    }
```